is bottom support or top support for a shelf better?
I am building a "railing" from 2x4 lumber that will sit 13 inches off of a wall by 6 foot across/wide. The rails will need to hold approximately 150 lbs spread roughly equally across the 6 foot span. The entirety of the mass will therefore be at the far edge of this railing (as opposed to a shelf where the weight isn't usually all right at the edge)
I can support this from the bottom with an angled brace - similar to wire-frame closet shelving 
or I can support the shelf structure from the top with a cable/chain, similar to this:

assuming adequate cable hardware (i.e. assume unlimited weight capacity for the cable and the top connector) , which of these supports would be preferable? I think the bottom support would be better overall but maybe I'm missing something?

I vote for bottom support

First you have to define "better".

Why are you asking about what is better for a shelf when you are not building a shelf.

It's easier to design support that relies on tension (i.e. top support) than compression (i.e. bottom support) but the advantage of bottom support is you don't have those pesky wires in the way all the time.
